# Proper manipulation of IEnumerable<foo>

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, concatenation, ienumerable

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552153/what-could-solves-this-multi-threaded-scenario-better-than-concurrent-collection?noredirect=1#comment45420458_28552153).

In a multi-threaded program, different threads each generate a very long list of results. When thread finished it's task, I would like to *Concatenate* the different lists into a single list. Please mind followings:

```
public struct AccEntry
{
    internal AccEntry(int accumulation)
        : this()
    {
        Accumulation = accumulation;
    }
    public int Accumulation { private set; get; }
}


internal class Functions
{
     internal Functions(Object lockOnMe, IEnumerable<AccEntry> results)
     {
          _lockOnMe = lockOnMe;
          _results = results;
          _result = new List<AccEntry>();
     }

     private IEnumerable<AccEntry> _results { set; get; }
     private List<AccEntry> _result { set; get; }

     internal void SomeFunction()
     {
          /// some time consuming process that builds _result
          lock(_lockOnMe)
          {
              /// The problem is here! _results is always null.
              if (_results == null) _results = _result;
              else _results = _results.Concat(_result);
          }
     }
}

public class ParentClass
{
     public void DoJob()
     {
          IEnumerable<AccEntry> results = null;
          /// initialize and launch multiple threads where each 
          /// has a new instance of Functions, and call SomeFunction.
     }
}
```

The problem, as mentioned in code, is that _results is always *null*. When on thread changes sets it to *_result* the other thread finds it *null* again. I also tried using a *ref* keyword in *Functions* constructor for *results*, but it did not change anything.

Assuming that followings execute as expected, I wonder what could be the point I miss on above-mentioned code?!!

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>();
List<int> listB = new List<int>();
listA.Add(10);
listB.Add(12);
IEnumerable<int> listC = null;
listC = listA;
listC = listC.Concat(listB);
```

Comment: You are never updating the variable "results" that is defined in the method DoJob() because you are passing it to the constructor of Functions by VALUE. A possible solution is to initialize it to new List() instead of null.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto   I tried ref keyword too, it did not work. Initialization by a *new List()* forces me to use *AddRange* instead of *Concat*, which in my application is considered a high performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are concatenating the items and assigning it back to the `_results` variable, that will replace the original value that you assigned to the variable. That new collection of items will be local to that instance.

Instead of using an `IEnumerable<>` that you have to replace to update it, use a `List<>` that you can add items to in place:

```
internal class Functions
{
     internal Functions(Object lockOnMe, List<AccEntry> results)
     {
          _lockOnMe = lockOnMe;
          _results = results;
          _result = new List<AccEntry>();
     }

     private object _lockOnMe;
     private List<AccEntry> _results;
     private List<AccEntry> _result;

     internal void SomeFunction()
     {
          /// some time consuming process that builds _result
          lock(_lockOnMe)
          {
              _results.AddRange(_result);
          }
     }
}
```

Just make sure to create the list before creating the `Functions` instances.

Comment: Lists are avoided on purpose because of the performance penalty. AddRange requires roughly 1 second to concatenate two lists each with 5 million items where Concat does the same operation in few milliseconds. Do you think there could possibly be any work around to use Concat instead of AddRange ?

Comment: @Hamed: That performance test is comparing apples and oranges. The `Concat` method doesn't actually concatenate the collections, it creates a query that will concatenate the collections when iterated. The `Concat` call is very fast because it doesn't do the actual work, that will be done when you iterate the result later on. If you actually realise the concatenated collections, you will see that `AddRange` is about ten times faster.

Comment: I just realized the point of *Concat*. When you want to iterate, it requires all concatenated references to be alive, which is not acceptable in my scenario.